# Как отобрать группы строк по условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','огурец','вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша','арбуз','груша','банан', 'груша', 'вишня','яблоко', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['франция','россия', 'сша','россия', 'франция','россия','сша', 'россия', 'гана','россия','россия', 'россия', 'албания', 'россия', np.nan, 'россия'],
'id': ['01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['январь','март','январь','март', 'сентябрь','март','март', 'март', 'ноябрь', 'январь','январь', 'март', 'январь', 'март', 'март', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
dates
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно оставить те записи групп `id` (то есть группируем по `id` и потом проверяем условие), в которых после строки со значением `россия` в колонке `страна` следует строка со значением страны отличным от значения `россия` и не `NaN`.

Как это можно сделать?

Пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
def pairs(ls):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(ls)-1):
        res.append([b[i],b[i+1]])
    return res

def orr(b,k):
    z = True
    for i in b:
        bulev = i == k
        z = z or bulev
    return z
df = dates.copy()
patterns = ["россия", "россия"]
res = df.groupby("id").filter(lambda x: orr(pairs(x["страна"].tolist()),patterns))
```

Но возникает ошибка:

> 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaxU поправил, спасибо что заметили

Comment: И как должен выглядеть результат если во входных данных будет,  например, сначала Украина, а потом Россия ? Т.е. если «россия» будет второй и последней строкой, а другая страна первой.

Comment: @MaxU такая группа не должна быть в результате. Важно что после строки со значением россия следует строка со значением отличным от россия (не считая NAN)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .groupby("id")
       .filter(
           lambda x: x.iloc[x["страна"].eq("россия").argmax() + 1:, 
                            df.columns.get_loc("страна")]
                      .fillna("россия")
                      .ne("россия")
                      .any()))
```

результат:

```
In [97]: res
Out[97]:
      фрукт   страна   id     месяц
0     груша  франция   01    январь
1    огурец   россия   01      март
2     вишня      сша   01    январь
3   абрикос   россия   02      март
4     груша  франция   02  сентябрь
5     арбуз   россия   03      март
6     груша      сша   03      март
7     банан   россия  011      март
8     груша     гана  011    ноябрь
9     вишня   россия  011    январь
10   яблоко   россия  011    январь
11    груша   россия    6      март
12    вишня  албания    6    январь
```

Пояснения:

1. сначала находим порядковый индекс первого вхождения "россия" в группе - `x["страна"].eq("россия").argmax()`
2. выбираем все значения в столбце `"страна"` в группе начиная с найденного в предыдущем шаге индекса + 1. Т.е. выбираем строки *начиная со следующей* после первого вхождения "россия" в группе - `x.loc[x["страна"].eq("россия").argmax() + 1:, df.columns.get_loc("страна")]`
3. меняем `NaN` -> `"россия"`: `.fillna("россия")`
4. проверяем есть ли в выбранных в предыдущих шагах значениях хотя бы одно значение отличное от "россия" - `.ne("россия").any()`

---

В том случае если значения индекса - монотонно возрастающая последовательность можно воспользоваться `.loc[]` и `Series.idxmax()`:

```
res = (df
       .groupby("id")
       .filter(
           lambda x: x.loc[x["страна"].eq("россия").idxmax() + 1:, "страна"]
                      .fillna("россия")
                      .ne("россия")
                      .any()))
```

Comment: получаю "The current behaviour of 'Series.argmax' is deprecated, use 'idxmax'
instead." Поэтому результат не тот на выходе

Comment: @formanite, какая у вас версия Pandas и Numpy? Попробуйте выполнить ответ как есть ничего не меняя для фрейма из вашего вопроса

Comment: pandas: 0.25.2
numpy: 1.17.5

Ничего не меняя запускал

Comment: @formanite, эта версия устарела - ей уже более 1.5 лет и за это время вышел новый `major release update` - 1.0, а сейчас почти все используют `1.2.x`. PS я исправил ответ - проверьте...

Comment: а если я хочу добавить доп условие, что помимо страны = россия , месяц = март, как это сделать?

lambda x: x.loc[(x["страна"].eq("россия") & x["месяц"].eq("март")).idxmax() + 1:, "страна"] - не подходит

Comment: задал вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1281713/255714

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2**

```
res= pd.DataFrame()

for i, g in dates.groupby("id"):
    if any(g["страна"].str.contains("россия")) and g["страна"].nunique()>1:
        if any([x > min(g[g.loc[:,"страна"]=="россия"].index) for x in g[g.loc[:,"страна"]!="россия"].index]):
            res = res.append(g)
```

res:

```
      фрукт   страна   id     месяц
0     груша  франция   01    январь
1    огурец   россия   01      март
2     вишня      сша   01    январь
7     банан   россия  011      март
8     груша     гана  011    ноябрь
9     вишня   россия  011    январь
10   яблоко   россия  011    январь
3   абрикос   россия   02      март
4     груша  франция   02  сентябрь
5     арбуз   россия   03      март
6     груша      сша   03      март
11    груша   россия    6      март
12    вишня  албания    6    январь
```

Comment: ответ не совпадает с ожидаемым результатом. Нужно применять это к группе id. А тут без группировки. Не могли бы показать как с группировкой это делать?

Comment: Мне кажется, что ответ как раз совпадёт с результатом с использованием группировки. Как вы получили свой "желаемый результат"?

Comment: в вопрсое есть два скриншота, вам нужно смотреть на второй - это и есть ожидаемый резульат. Нам нужно к групированным данным по колонке id применить условие: если в группе id после строки со страной "россия" следует строка со страной отличной от "россия" то все строки этой группы оставляем, а если после строки в группе id со значением "россия" следует NaN или значение "россия" , то строки этой группы удаляем

Comment: Также в вашем результате указаны не все строки группы id = "01"

Comment: @formanite, ставить минус человеку, который пытается вам помочь - не очень дальновидная стратегия ;) Даже если ответ неправильный...

Comment: @MaxU а я думал, что надо ставить до момента , когда будет исправлен ответ.  Как я понимаю, это неправильно. Тогда Поставлю плюс, извините

Comment: @MaxU не подключитесь к решению, вы ранее помогали сильно)

Comment: @formanite я обновил ответ. Вы бы, кстати, сами подключались к решению. я вам уже говорил, что за все время вашей истории с фруктами я не видел ни строчки вашего кода.

Comment: @strawdog я бы с радостью, но в таких кейсах я даже не представляю какой метод подбирать. Везде, где мне помогали были методы assign и еще что-то. но хорошего объяснения логики таких методов я не нашел, поэтому самостоятельно не всегда удается что-то придумать, как в данном случае.

Comment: Хм, кстати, ваш вопрос навел меня на мысль, что даже при таком решении не все условия будут выполняться.

Comment: @strawdog, действительно, если в группе 4 строки и на второй строке страна россия, и на третьей португалия, то в результате получим не все строки этой группы, пытаюсь понять как можжно этой обойти, но пока ничего не придумал

Comment: @strawdog обновил датафрейм в задании, теперь видно , что не все строки группы 011 выводятся в результате

Comment: @strawdog к заданию прикрепил мою попытку решить задачу. Посмотрите пожалуйста, возможно удасться понять, что нужно изменить в моем коде

Comment: обновил ответ. в нем есть проверка на нахождения "россии" в группе.